# Find the number of six digit numbers in which sum of the squares of the digits is 9

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of six digit numbers in which sum of the squares of the digits is 9.

---

Let $abcdef$ be the number and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2=9$
As squares end with $1,4,5,6,9.$ So $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\{4,5\}.$
How should i solve further?

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint:  how many digits $>3$ can there be?  How many $3's$ can there be?

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider the number $003000$ to be a six-digit number. I'd call it $3000$. In other words, it would be very odd if leading zeros were allowed.

Comment: Umm, why do you have $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\{4,5\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**

$$9=0+0+0+0+0+9$$
$$=1+1+1+1+1+4$$
$$=0+0+0+1+4+4$$

So there are
$$6+6+6\binom {5}{2}=72$$ numbers.

Comment: This isn't a hint. It's the answer

Comment: @Χpẘ have you found the same result.

Comment: I found the same three "forms", however wasn't sure if leading zeroes were allowed. So I didn't count the number of combinations of each form.

Answer (score 2):

No, $f$ cannot be $4$ or $5$ because the sum is too large.  All the digits have to be $0,1,2,3$.  Make a list of the multisets of digits that have the proper sum, then compute the ways to order each multiset.  For example, one choice is $\{0,0,0,0,0,3\}$   How many numbers have those for digits.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean about $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \{4,5\}$, the set of digits is either $\{0,0,0,0,0,3\}$, $\{1,1,1,1,1,2\}$ or $\{0,0,0,1,2,2\}$ and then you just have to work out the number of possibilities for each and sum them.